# Odd behaviour with INSERT INTO ... SELECT with Excel 2007 SQL

Tags: sql, excel, vbscript

Now then. I have this VBScript script

```
Const inputfile = "New Microsoft Office Excel Worksheet (2).xlsx"

dim ado: set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
ado.connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""" _
                        & inputfile & """;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"

ado.CursorLocation = 3
ado.open

ado.Execute "INSERT INTO [recalculated] ([TIME PERIOD]) " & _
            "SELECT Format(CDate(Mid([TIME PERIOD], 8, 13)), 'mm/dd/yyyy') " & _
            "AS [TIME PERIOD] FROM [input]"
ado.close
```

The tables in the workbook are named ranges in their own worksheets

`input`:

[image: input table]

`recalculated` (ie a blank table with the same column name):

[image: recalculated table]

The script runs without raising an error however the data is inserted into the `input` table instead of `recalculated`:

[image: resulting input table]

(I note that this is actually different behaviour to what I was seeing earlier - I added the `TOP 3` to the SQL query for this question because originally the table was overwritten and not appended to)

But if I change the expression to something else, eg

```
ado.Execute "INSERT INTO [recalculated] ([TIME PERIOD]) " & _
            " SELECT TOP 3 'cheese' AS [TIME PERIOD] FROM [input]"
```

it works fine, `recalculated` is populated and `input` is left as is.

Anyone know what's going on and how I can fix it? At the very least, can someone reproduce this as just to prove I'm not a lunatic?

---

I've just found that this works as expected if the workbook is already open in Excel when the script is run

Comment: Does your script work if your column name in the new table's field isn't TIME PERIOD? This might tell you if there is a reference issue in your query.

Comment: @jennifer no, even if I change the column names and remove the `Format(CDate(Mid([<column name>], 8, 13))` to just leave `<column name>`, it does the same thing

Comment: I tried the code above and it worked for me. There were two small changes I made: i. `TimePeriod` rather than `Time Period` ii. Recalculated referred to `$a$1:$a$2`

Comment: Thanks @Remou - did you see what I saw without those changes?

Comment: @oracle No, I did not. It worked as it should. Perhaps you could try again with a new workbook?

Comment: hmmm, i did that. something must be corrupt somewhere. were you working in office 2007?

Comment: @oracle Yes. (BTW without atsignname, I may miss your comments)

Answer (score 0):

When I run the code it works as I would expect i.e. the inserts go into the `recalculated` table.

Here's similar script that recreates your scenario but using a new workbook created from scratch:

```
' Const inputfile = "New Microsoft Office Excel Worksheet (2).xlsx"
Const inputfile_with_path = "C:\New Microsoft Office Excel Worksheet (2).xlsx"

Dim ado: Set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
ado.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""" _
                        & inputfile_with_path & """;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"

ado.CursorLocation = 3
ado.Open

ado.Execute "CREATE TABLE [input] ([TIME PERIOD] VARCHAR(255));"
ado.Execute "INSERT INTO [input] VALUES ('WEEK OF JUN 21, 2010 (B)');"
ado.Execute "INSERT INTO [input] VALUES ('WEEK OF JUN 07, 2010 (B)');"
ado.Execute "INSERT INTO [input] VALUES ('WEEK OF JUN 21, 2010 (B)');"
ado.Execute "INSERT INTO [input] VALUES ('WEEK OF JAN 04, 2010 (B)');"
ado.Execute "INSERT INTO [input] VALUES ('WEEK OF JAN 04, 2010 (B)');"

ado.Execute "CREATE TABLE [recalculated] ([TIME PERIOD] VARCHAR(255));"

ado.Execute "INSERT INTO [recalculated] ([TIME PERIOD]) " & _
            "SELECT Format(CDate(Mid([TIME PERIOD], 8, 13)), 'mm/dd/yyyy') " & _
            "AS [TIME PERIOD] FROM [input]"

ado.Close
```

Comment: thanks for your answer - are you saying you could reproduce the issue I was seeing and that the above script corrected the issue?

Comment: @oracle certified professional: I've edited my answer. Hope it is clearer this time.